# Backendless c# desktop application saving data but by empty or null values

Tags: c#, null, save, desktop, backendless

I have a desktop app written in c# and I added app id and key id
and used this code to add data to database but the data is always empty or null.

```cs
var film = new Film();
film.setName(“soooft”);
film.setGenre(“aaa”);
film.setPlot(“fdgveqw”);
film.setUrl(“gdfwrw”);

var f = Backendless.Data.Of<Film>().Save(film);
```

Comment: Just to confirm.. records are being created but with no data in the fields? can you provide us the class for `Film`.  I'm interested in whether you are exposing properties or fields on it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your dev. environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: What are Backendless, Data and Save?

Comment: I've found this: https://backendless.com/docs/dotnet/data_data_object.html That link will explain others what Backendless is and what's been done here. He's following the code example, but most likely not using public properties or fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled Backendless and it's a third-party solution. (See https://github.com/Backendless/.NET-SDK)

Usage gets explained at https://backendless.com/docs/dotnet/data_data_object.html

But I'm suspicious about why you use setName(), setGenre(), setPlot and setUrl in your code. Seems your Film class is missing properties. I would expect you'd be writing this instead:

```
var film = new Film();
film.Name = “soooft”;
film.Genre = “aaa”;
film.Plot = “fdgveqw”;
film.Url = “gdfwrw”;
```

But that would mean those fields are declared as public properties in your class like this:

```
public class Film
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

So I don't know why you have those setName and other methods. The Backendless API specifies that these fields need to be public properties so it can read them through reflection. Your code seems to suggests that they're not proper properties as indicated by their example and my code of the Film() class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use public get/set properties instead of private fields and the data will be saved properly.